# I converted text data to jquery object but the created one was not what I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert text data to jquery object and want to use 'find()' method or 'filter()' method or some other methods which jquery has.
But somehow, the innerHtml of the converted jquery object is not what I expected..
I want to know what is going on.
http://jsfiddle.net/LxXtz/14/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="lib/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #parts{
        display: none;
    }
    -->
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#execution').on('click', function () {
                var parts = $('#parts').html(); //Parts is text data. I create the data from html just for this demo.
                var partsobj = $(parts); // Convert to jQuery object.
                console.log(partsobj.html()); // Why not be outputted innerHtml of #parts??
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="execution" value="Execute" />
<div id="parts">
    <div id="div1">
        <div>This is in Div1</div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">This is Div2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting below from `$('#parts').html()`

```
<div id="div1">
    <div>This is in Div1</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">This is Div2</div>
```

Then when you converts it to jquery object, it turns to array containing 3 elements,

```
Object[div#div1, <TextNode textContent="\n ">, div#div2]
```

So using the `.html()` gives the first element innerHTML only. That's

```
<div>This is in Div1</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/LxXtz/16/. Check the console.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/html/ states:

"Description: Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements."
"If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned."

Your partsobj matches 3 entries; div, textnode, div. One way to resolve it is to loop through them with each.

```
partsobj.each(function(){
    if($(this).html())
        $('#result').text($('#result').text()+$(this).html())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = $('#parts').children(); 
console.log(parts);
```

that will give you an array of the html elements.  If you want the raw html of those children elements.

```
var parts = $('#parts').children(); 
$.each({parts, function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

so you want the html of `div#execution`, then to insert it into `div#result`. if you want to move it then

```
$('#execution').on('click', function () {
  $('#result').append($('#parts').html())
});
```

is this what you mean?